# ASP.Net Core API error 500 in Windows 10 IIS

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to deploy ASP.Net Core web api on Windows 10 IIS. But it's failing with error 500 failed to load resource : the server responded with error 500 in Chrome

Environment

1. Windows 10 professional
2. Visual Studio 2019 including latest updates. Version is 16.11.4
3. Downloaded asp.net core hosting bundle and installed

Steps

1. Enabled Internet information services using "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. Using "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager", created a website "testpolicy", with port 8061, folder inetpub/wwwroot/testpolicy
   Also changed the application pool setting in IIS for the site, i.e. .NET CLR version to "No managed Code"
3. Using VS Studio, created a new WebAPI project. Tested within Visual studio and it works as expected
   The name of the controller is policyController

The extract from the code is as follows

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PolicyController : ControllerBase {
}
```

Published the project to IIS using Web Deploy option with following parameters
a) server as http://localhost
b) site name as testpolicy
c) dest url as http://localhost:8061

4. from browser, tried to execute below, but get 500 server error

http://localhost:8061/api/policy

Comment: Any logs or exceptions you can share?

Comment: Read what FRT says, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis